# How do I calculate the mean of a column by a factor - R

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis

I'm pretty new to R. I'm trying to calculate the daily means for the column "Temperature.10m".

I've tried:

```
aggregate(x=AverageData$Temperature.10m, by= list(AverageData$Day), FUN = mean)
```

based on other posts but I am not getting the correct values. The data set contains temperatures for every hour of everyday. Attached is the picture of the data set.

[image: AverageData]

Comment: Do you have a `numeric` column for 'Temerature.10m'

Comment: Without a small reproducible example, it is difficult to know the exact issue

Comment: By daily means do you mean year/month/day means?

Comment: What do you mean by “not getting the correct values”? The answerers can just guess currently… Please [edit] your question to be more specific. See also [“It’s not working” is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the dataset have some missing values (`NA`).  An option is to use `na.action`

```
aggregate(Temperature.10m ~ Day, AverageData, mean, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = NULL)
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
AverageData %>%
     group_by(Day) %>%
     summarise(Mean = mean(Temperature.10m, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the data includes fields for year, month, and day, average daily temperature likely summaries across hours, and must be calculated by combination of `Year`, `Month`, and `Day`.

```
library(dplyr)
AverageData %>% group_by(Year,Month,Day) %>%
   summarise(avg = mean(Temperature.10m, na.rm = TRUE))
```

If one needs different average daily temperatures by `Site`, it also must be included in the `group_by()`.

```
library(dplyr)
AverageData %>% group_by(Site,Year,Month,Day) %>%
   summarise(avg = mean(Temperature.10m, na.rm = TRUE))
```

One could simplify this by combining the year, month, and day information into a single date variable. One way to do this is with `lubridate`.

```
library(lubridate)
AverageData$date <- ymd(sprintf("%4d-$02d-%02d",AverageData$year,AverageData$month,AverageData$day))
```

Now, the cross-site daily averages would look like this in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
AverageData %>% group_by(date) %>%
   summarise(avg = mean(Temperature.10m, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!! Thank you so much for the clarity

Comment: @VanessaMadrid - Thanks, Vanessa. If the answer was helpful, please accept it. Also, you'll get more relevant help faster if you read [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include a small subset of data with your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way by first creating a `Date` column with `ISOdate` and `as.Date`. The call to `as.Date` is needed because `ISOdate` sets the time to 12:00:00.

```
df1$Date <- with(df1, ISOdate(Year, Month, Day))
df1$Date <- as.Date(df1$Date)
```

Now `aggregate` by `Date` computing the mean values.

```
aggregate(Temperature.10m ~ Date, df1, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
#        Date Temperature.10m
#1 2016-04-17       -15.72627
#2 2016-04-18       -14.91346
#3 2016-04-19       -15.76245
```

Or, with package `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(MeanTemp = mean(Temperature.10m, na.rm = TRUE))
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Date       MeanTemp
#  <date>        <dbl>
#1 2016-04-17    -15.7
#2 2016-04-18    -14.9
#3 2016-04-19    -15.8
```

**Data creation code**

```
set.seed(1234)
Hour <- 0:23
Day <- 18:20
Month <- 4
Year <- 2016
df1 <- expand.grid(Year, Month, Day, Hour)
names(df1) <- c("Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour")
df1 <- df1[with(df1, order(Year, Month, Day, Hour)), ]
df1$Temperature.10m <- runif(nrow(df1), -20, -10)
```